# Convert factor into logical datatype

Tags: r, data-conversion

I have a two levels factor in my data that I want to convert to logical

```
a <- str(df$y)
a
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I use `as.logical(df$y)` to convert them into logical. However, the data turn into `NA`

```
summary(a)

      Mode    NA's 
    logical  500000
```

At which point do I fail to convert the data?

Comment: Since you have a factor variable, I suggest you convert to character, then to integer and finally to logical: `as.logical(as.integer(levels(a))[a])`. You can read about it in the "Value" section of `?as.logical`

Comment: There is a short cut: `y <- factor(0:1); str(y); as.logical(as.integer(y) - 1L)` returns `[1] FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: Just test for equality with whatever level you want to be "true": `df$y == "1"`. The result will be your logical vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> At which point do I fail to convert the data?

I'd argue that you at no point fail to convert the data, it's the function that is a bit odd and fails to understand the nature of your data.

If you read `?as.logical` you'll see that when input is factor the levels (which are character) are used in the conversion. The only valid character strings are all variations of "true" and "false", everything else, including "0" and "1", returns NA. 0 and 1 are however interpreted as `FALSE` and `TRUE`, respectively, when they are given as numeric, hence all the following works:

```
y <- factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0))

as.logical(as.integer(levels(y)[y]))
as.logical(as.integer(y) - 1L)
as.logical(as.integer(as.character(y)))
```

A bit cumbersome, I know, but that's how it is.

Comment: Also `y == 1`, much less cumbersome.

Comment: Hah, true. Doesn't tell you much about why the straight `as.logical()` didn't work though.

Comment: it's working very well. I do think the `?as.logical` have to be read carefully to understand the function. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, there is a strightforward method.

As you have 2 levels factor, **identify whats true and false**

```
df <- data.frame(y=factor(sample(c("0","1"),10,replace = TRUE)))

str(df$y)
#  Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

levels(df$y) <- c(FALSE,TRUE)
df$y <- as.logical(df$y)

str(df$y)
# logi [1:10] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a little too late to be helpful, but I ran into a similar problem and found a fix:

```
as.logical(as.integer(data.frame$column))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Should probably note that this works *only if* the factor representation for `TRUE` is 1 and `FALSE` is 0. Any other value for the factors gets coerced into `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `==` to create TRUE and FALSE values:

```
y = factor(c(0, 1, NA))
y == "1"
# [1] FALSE  TRUE    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `==` operator in `as.logical()` to identify which factor value is `TRUE`.

```
as.logical(factor_vector == 'True value here')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956497/what-is-going-on-with-r-coercing-true-string-to-true-logical